# reCAPTCHA callback not working for Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I am trying to implement phone auth in my NextJS website, and I have added the reCAPTCHA code in my useEffect , but it is not fired when the button with that id is clicked. There is no error as well. Here is the reCAPTCHA code:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('btnPersonalInfoSubmit', {
                    'size': 'invisible',
                    'callback': (response) => {
                        console.log(response);
                      handlePersonalInfoUpdate();
                    },
                    'expired-callback': () => {
                        console.log('expired');
                    },
                    'error-callback': (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                }, auth);
```

There is no output. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had to add `window.recaptchaVerifier.render()` at the end. Final code:

```
                if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
                    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('btnPersonalInfoSubmit', {
                        'size': 'invisible',
                        'callback': (response) => {
                            handlePersonalInfoUpdate();
                        },
                        'expired-callback': () => {
                            console.log('expired');
                        },
                        'error-callback': (error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    }, auth);
                    window.recaptchaVerifier.render()
                }
```